Is there any significance to “standing” in Matthew 20:1-6?
Matthew 20:1-16 (LSB)

1 For the kingdom of heaven is like a landowner who went out early in the morning to hire laborers for his vineyard. 2 Now when he had agreed with the laborers for a denarius for the day, he sent them into his vineyard. 3 And he went out about the third hour and saw others standing idle in the marketplace; 4 and to those he said, ‘You also go into the vineyard, and whatever is right I will give you.’ And so they went. 5 Again he went out about the sixth and the ninth hour, and did the same thing. 6 And about the eleventh hour he went out and found others standing around; and he said to them, ‘Why have you been standing here idle all day long?’ 7 They said to him, ‘Because no one hired us.’ He said to them, ‘You go into the vineyard too.’ 8 “Now when evening came, the owner of the vineyard said to his foreman, ‘Call the laborers and pay them their wages, beginning with the last group to the first.’ 9 And when those hired about the eleventh hour came, each one received a denarius. 10 And when those hired first came, they supposed that they would receive more; but each of them also received a denarius. 11 Now when they received it, they were grumbling at the landowner, 12 saying, ‘These last men have worked only one hour, and you have made them equal to us who have borne the burden of the day and the scorching heat.’ 13 But he answered and said to one of them, ‘Friend, I am doing you no wrong; did you not agree with me for a denarius? 14 Take what is yours and go, but I wish to give to this last man the same as to you. 15 Is it not lawful for me to do what I wish with what is my own? Or is your eye envious because I am generous?’ 16 So the last shall be first, and the first last.

In the parable, “standing” is repeated three times. The first group is not explicitly said to be standing. Later groups seem to be standing.
In the parable, the ones in the first group are the ones who are “grumbling” and are “envious”.
In other books of the Bible, “standing” often has a meaning but I don’t see where Jesus tells others to stand in the Bible, so I don’t see a good context for His use of “standing”.
Does the repetition of “standing” in this parable have any significance in separating the first group from the later groups?
I tend to consider the first group as the Jews who rejected Jesus but am open to other interpretations, and/or to be told there is no significance in “standing”.

Is there any significance to “standing” in Matthew 20:1-6?
I would think so.
'To stand' can denote possession of enough strength and agility in readiness to do something or to take action.
The greek word translated 'stand' or 'standing'(KJV) is histemi. There are groups of drugs called anti-histemine. Anti-histemine means 'to stand in opposition to', 'to withstand' or 'to stand against'.
Paul uses the word 'anti-histemi' in Eph.6:13 as 'withstand'(KJV) when he was teaching on spiritual warfare. He also used the word 'histemi' in the same chapter such as in verses 11 and 13.
To be able to stand therefore, denotes readiness to expend stored energy  to fulfil a purpose or to achieve an intension.
Back to Matt.20:1-16.
They had energy; they wanted to expend their energy to do something and earn a living for the day but there was nothing available to expend there energy on  - they were standing idle. They were ready but no channel.
They remained standing until they were called into some work to do.

Standing up is a reflex action that shows that the person is up to do something , eagerly waiting for something, is too troubled to sit down and so on. A laborer who eagerly waits for someone  to hire him, but is comfortably seated,  gives a wrong signal to the passersby- that he is idle.Also, the one who keeps standing is better able to meet the job-giver vis- a-vis one who is sitting down. In those days when chairs or benches in public places were hard to come  by, ordinary people squatted on the ground .   As many men  are accustomed to, they soon engage themselves with games like gambling to pass time ( Prov 28:19).
Now, laborers not hired even till the eleventh hour, were still hoping for someone to engage them , and were eagerly waiting for their turn. Jesus' specific mention of their standing definitely has a message: that one should , to the very end, hope and trust in the abundant grace and infinite mercy of the Lord.
